# How can I ignore all folders whose names are of the form <pattern>*?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have several folders with names of the form

```
captchaXXX/
captchaYYY/
captchaZZZ/
```

and so on...

What should I put in my `.gitignore` file to ignore all folders in my project that match the pattern `captcha*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as simple as `captcha*/`